# Can we get rid of the threshold of 15 chars for comments?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, character-limit

I understand that there is an upper limit. But why do you have to type at least 15 characters to post a comment?
It is easy to work around it anyway (like adding dots or other useless things).

Comment: I don't have any problem with comments not being allowed to be less than 15 characters, but what I think is annoying is that comments can't be more than 600 characters.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'd say no, it discourages comments like "lol" which don't really add anything of value.

Like you say, it's possible to work around the limit, but you have to go out your way to do so (I think it encourages good commenting in the way the badges encourages good questioning/answering)

Comment: Your badges argument convinced me. I think I will eat Ólafur's cake ;-) (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/700/can-we-get-rid-of-the-threshold-of-15-chars-for-comments/708#708)

Comment: lol           .

Comment: It doesn't encourage _good_ commenting, it encourages _verbose_ commenting. Quantity != quality.

Comment: There's not many "high quality" comments that can be made in < 15 characters.. There might be a few exceptions, but I imagine most comments that length would be, as Workshop Alex demonstrates, "lol"

Comment: lololololololol

Comment: After much careful consideration, the undersigned has come to the conclusion that this elaborate answer requires a comment, namely, a heartfelt "LOL".

Comment: In other words, there are always weapons.  If a comment has no value, at least let it be short.

Comment: @Graeme said it all. This lower limit is silly and annoying when I write concise comments. The lower limit doesn't discourage "lol" comments just like declaring knives illegal wouldn't discourage murders. But hey, keep working against me, I'll keep working against you, and we're all happy -- aren't we?

Comment: Stupid, stupid, STUPID stackoverflow logic! This comment is over 15 chars long. And now surely you see how encouraged I am to write detailed and complete comments. YAY higher quality for stackoverflow!!1  STUPIDD!!!11

Comment: If comments don't add any value, then click the "flag as noise" link.  Limiting the number of characters does very little to help solve this problem.

Comment: ``````lol``````

Answer (score 40):

I find it .... errr ... well ... amusing, ridiculous, surprising, interesting and all kinds of other things, that a large percentage of the honorable meta crowd really thinks that a minimum character limit encourages "thoughtful comments". Since when are people that talk more more thoughtful? Since when are long texts more thoughtful? Since when haven't you been talking to your marketing department? Since when is more code better code?

And, best of all, IMHO: Since when is saying "Thank you!" considered a thoughtless venture into AOL land?

Comment: "Since when are people that talk more more thoughtful?" Thumbs up!

Answer (score 23):

You can put spaces between the last characters.

```
Yes                    .
```

This will work and looks like this

```
Yes .
```

Due to how HTML truncates regular spaces. (see my comment on the question)

But I like that there is a minimum. Kinda forces us to talk more about the item in question.

Comment: You like the minimum, but circumvent it. Big deal ;-)

Comment: That's what I call having my cake and eating it too.

Comment: You can put spaces at the end, after the last character - since the format of the comments is like "(comment)(space)-(space)(commenter name)", the spaces at the end will be truncated into the first space between the comment and the dash. Example:

Comment: This apparently just got "fixed". >:(

Answer (score 11):

The types of questions asked on SO tend not to be yes/no types of questions and generally require a bit of explanation. Answers are, on average, a few sentences at least, and responders seem to enjoy posting thorough and detailed answers.

That said, I suppose there's no reason to impose a minimum on trusted users with high enough rep.

Comment: Agreed. I don't see why people with more than 2000 reputation should have such a limit - they are trusted enough by SO to edit other people's questions and answers, so they should be trusted enough not to leave pointless comments even if they are short.

Answer (score 10):

I'm for lowering this limit too. It's silly to put in "Comment       ." just to get it posted. Didn't it used to be 10? Can't we get 10 at least?

Preventing mistakes is a non-argument. It only stops accidental posting if you post 14 characters or less and if you've done that well it's easy enough to copy and paste into a new comment and delete the old one.

Comment: Besides we can now edit comments anyway.

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes the best answers can be nothing more than a word or two - by referring the reader to a concept they were unaware of which will completely solve their problem.

I am slightly annoyed at the hackiness of adding whitespace to the response to get around the limitation.

Answer (score 8):

One of the most nonsense things that come with the limit is when you reply to someone.

If someone points out a problem in my answer, if they have a long name a comment like:

`@IHaveAReallyLongName fixed` Is a legitimate comment, but on the other end: `@short fixed` is not legitimate. It makes no sense that who i'm replying to should require shorter or longer comments.

Answer (score 2):

The limit encourages thoughtful comments, and I like it that way. The last thing we need is a bunch of "Me too!" comments! So I think we should keep the limit.

Comment: I have this problem too! Plz do you have a solution? Isn't this much better than "me too!" because now I'm being more verbose and therefore you get to spend more time reading my comment! Clearly longer comments are more legit than short ones.

Answer (score 1):

I got sick of the umpteen bajillion "bugs" opened on this, so we "fixed the bug".

This is now less easy to bypass; perhaps one should consider populating their comment with something meaningful of 15 characters or more? Perhaps if one has less to say than that, one should keep one's thoughts to him or herself?

A modest proposal.

Enjoy.

Comment: sweeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeet ;)

Comment: Short things that are valid comments: "Link please?" "Spam" "see my answerer" "OK" (as part of an exchange). There is a (finite?) set of things where padding it to 15 makes the comment LESS meaningful. Could we get a white list for some of the more common ones? -- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30934/can-we-get-a-whitelist-of-short-comments

Comment: [Use links](http://google.com)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could allow the original question owner to circumvent the minimum length.

Mostly I just want to say "Thank you"

"Thank you ............" just isn't quite the same.

Comment: You could maybe say the person's name, too. "Thank you, Gareth."

Comment: if all you need to say is "thanks!" then clicking upvote or accept should suffice

Comment: That's astonishingly impersonal :)

Comment: @Jeff I feel much better if somebody say "Thanks", than if somebody upvotes my question. You can't even know who voted that way..

Comment: "Thank you" is just noise.  We readers don't care that you are thankful for the answer.  We only want to read the answer.  Stack Exchange exists to distill out the questions and answers from the cruft, so we aren't wading through pages of noise to find the signal, like in the days of discussion forums.  That said, this policy is stupid because there are lots of legitimate comments under 15 characters.

Comment: You know what I do? I write this: [Thanks!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/700) — The markup counts towards the minimum :)

Comment: Yeah, okay, socially awkward programmers feel saying "thank you" has "no value", news at 11. "Pages of noise", seriously? The #1 most common complaint I hear about the Stack(Overflow|Exchange) community is that it is impersonal, cold, and bureaucratic. This kind of thing has a _very real_ impact on how likely people will want to participate in your community.

Comment: Thank you.[​](http://example.com)