# Spaces getting past minimum character limit

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, character-limit, hidden-features

It appears that now you can no longer just put spaces at the end of text to get past the character limit.  You can still put them in the middle, where they get truncated to a single space.

I always thought that being able to use spaces to get past the minimum character limit was one of the best hidden-features of the S[OFU] sites.

Please vote to get this reimplemented.

Comment: They're not truncated - they still show up in the source - but browsers always render multiple spaces as one space.

Comment: QQ                more

Comment: That doesn't help when I want to comment "Yes" !!!

Answer (score 4):

when doing length check, switched to `.RemoveExtraSpaces()` on the server side instead of `.Trim()`

Comment: Was it really a problem?

Comment: it wasn't really a problem; I didn't care either way. But the weekly opening of "bugs" from ZOMG HAXOR programmers discovering the same boring trick was too much for me to take. So, we fixed the "bug".

Comment: ␠␠␠␠␠␠␠␠␠␠␠␠␠␠␠

Answer (score 2):

As long as the character limit exists, and it [seems that it will](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17183/do-away-with-minimum-char-limits-on-comments/23574#23574), it makes sense for it to be enforced. 15 characters isn't a whole lot, really. Can anyone come up with a good example where it's not possible to expand the thought to meet the quota?

Comment: How did you do that Kyle??

Comment: I can't answer tour question with NO because it's not 15 characters thus forcing me to type more... #fail

Comment: Not tour rather your....

Comment: @Isaac: fretje is correct, just put a bunch of spaces between backquotes. but don't tell anyone.