# Should I upvote an answer when I think there may yet be better answers?

Tags: discussion, voting, unanswered-questions, up-votes

I've found that I'm hesitant to upvote an answer when it is ok, but I could see room for improvement, since the upvote would take the question off the unanswered list.

Am I simply missing a piece of etiquette?  Has anyone else noticed this effect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**IMHO**

You should use votes how you like.  They are yours to cast.

*I upvote right answers, even if they aren't the best.*

Comment: +1, even though this is not the best answer

Comment: Ha, thanks! (15 char lim harder to bypass.....)

Comment: @jinguy: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23595/spaces-getting-past-minimum-character-limit/23601#23601

Answer (score 5):

I upvote an answer if it helped answering the question in any way. If I feel like there is something missing from the answer, I put a comment on it indicating the room for improvement. Same goes for good questions that need improvement.

Answer (score 2):

Are you better off with the answer than without it? If so, upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

If I can provide the improvment, I write an answer. If not, I upvote the existing one. I may also ask for precisions in a comment.