# Don't count non-printing characters, HTML comments or other content not displayed toward minimum character requirements

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, character-limit, special-characters

A follow-up to [Enforcing a question minimum character length?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/enforcing-a-question-minimum-character-length), and an extension of [Spaces getting past minimum character limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23595/spaces-getting-past-minimum-character-limit).

[This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10518) shows that it is possible to circumvent minimum character requirements using null bytes.  Can we exclude such non-printing characters as ASCII `NULL` and other control characters from counting toward minimum character requirements?

**Edit:** Users have demonstrated that [HTML comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94244/html-comments-can-circumvent-minimum-post-length-limits), unmatched or invalid HTML tags, and other content that is not displayed after Markdown parsing can be used to bypass such requirements as well.  Can we cover this case as well, except for links?

Comment: There are other ways to get around it than using those characters. What does it solve?

Comment: IMO this is just trying way too hard for what is, at worst, an amusing oddity rather than a dangerous exploit.

Comment: Yeah, why do you want to prevent this... it's so much fun!

Comment: [Soft hyphen](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200181/bypassing-minimum-comment-length-with-soft-hyphen-alt-0173)

Comment: You should also not count the `@username` part towards the minimum characters in a case in which it will be stripped from the output. Like this case: If I type `@DragonLordtheFiery` at the beginning of this comment, it should not count toward the character minimum as it will be stripped from the output.

Comment: ­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: I think that content that isn't displayed shouldn't count towards the maximum character limit for comments. It's really annoying when I need to link to a page with a long URL in a comment and don't have enough characters for anything else. For example, if I add one more character to the following comment, it will be too long.

Comment: [This is almost too long.](https://www.google.se/search?q=I+think+that+content+that+isn%27t+displayed+shouldn%27t+count+towards+the+maximum+character+limit+for+comments.+It%27s+really+annoying+when+I+need+to+link+to+a+page+with+a+long+URL+in+a+comment+and+don%27t+have+enough+characters+for+anything+else.&oq=I+think+that+content+that+isn%27t+displayed+shouldn%27t+count+towards+the+maximum+character+limit+for+comments.+It%27s+really+annoying+when+I+need+to+link+to+a+page+with+a+long+URL+in+a+comment+and+don%27t+have+enough+characters+for+anything+else.&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure this is going to actually help anything. As users who can't reach the minimum character count have demonstrated, they'd rather find odd ways of avoiding the minimum limit that require more effort than just typing some extra text that supplements their answer.

**Which of these would you rather see?**

> Yes.

or

> #### ***Yes.***

or

> Yes. ____________

If people really don't want to think up a simple 15 characters, there's nothing that's going to stop them. Most users who don't know about the null byte characters and the HTML comments just fill the space with random, meaningless characters such as `sjfgshjfs` to bypass the limit, or use other styles (headers, bold, italics) to make the text stand out when it doesn't need to stand out.

Personally, I'd much rather see the first one. It may be a character bypass, but at least it doesn't look stupid in general when you look at it. Ultimately answers which use these are probably not real answers anyways* and will end up deleted or get fixed by someone else.

<sub>* Unless you're on Meta.</sub>

Comment: You're right.  I concede. :P

Answer (score 17):

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: To this day, it's still possible to use null bytes to bypass minimum character requirements.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Well, null bytes have no place in text fields, so why should they be allowed?  That's the point I'm trying to make.  In fact, under certain circumstances, this can be a [security vulnerability](http://hakipedia.com/index.php/Poison_Null_Byte).  This is another example of failing to sanitize input.

Comment: I haven't used null bytes, but the zero-width space character `U+200B`

Comment: Okay, so they aren't null bytes.  It turns out my hex editor didn't properly support Unicode...

Comment: Null bytes may work, but this is nothing new. Zero-width spaces, soft hyphens, zero-width non-joiners... there's no point in banning them all (that's what happened to the ZWNJ and it really didn't work).