# An answer without any content?

Tags: support, answers, special-characters

Randomly looking around SO, I come across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12208421/1079354).  What catches my eye is an unusual answer in that it's not worded at all:

> [image: Post without any content]

Seems like a bug to me...may warrant looking into.

Comment: Reminds me of the other recent question [Potential security risk: Null bytes accepted as part of text](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145534/potential-security-risk-null-bytes-accepted-as-part-of-text).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's just a bunch of empty characters:

```
&#1;&#1;&#1;&#1;&#1;&#1;&#1;&#1;&#1;&#1;&#1;&#1;&#1;&#1;
```

Likely he posted an answer, realized it was wrong or otherwise, and removed all the content within the 5 minute grace period rather than deleting it, which he should have done. He might have thought he was going to update it with a different answer later, and maybe forgot. Happens more often than you might think (not the leaving it there empty part, though).

Comment: Notwithstanding that it happens a lot, why wouldn't this be filtered out as empty strings?  They don't actually print anything out to the screen.

Comment: @Makoto: See [Don't count non-printing characters, HTML comments or other content not displayed toward minimum character requirements](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137006/dont-count-non-printing-characters-html-comments-or-other-content-not-displaye)

Comment: @makoto: If someone goes out of his way to create a post without useful content, the system can't really stop it. There is not really a point in filtering out all kinds of obscure edge cases if you can always write "ehdhududfuuhhdgufifyfujhdudh" and get around the filter anyway.