# Null bytes accepted as part of text (not really)

Tags: support, special-characters

<s>I think it's OK to post this because it's already clear that null bytes can be entered into posts and comments, and possibly other fields.</s>

If one takes a look at [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137006/dont-count-non-printing-characters-html-comments-or-other-content-not-displaye/137018#137018) , it's clear that one can use null bytes to circumvent minimum character limits.  However, this can create problems well beyond circumvention of minimum character limits.

This is an instance of [CWE-158](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/158.html) and is a **potential security risk**, creating the risk of attacks such as poison null bytes ([CWE-626](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/626.html); see also [Hakipedia article](http://hakipedia.com/index.php/Poison_Null_Byte)).  The Stack Exchange team should strongly consider stripping any null bytes from *any field* where a user can enter text at the time it is submitted.

**Edit:** For those who aren't seeing the null bytes, I suspect that the browser is neutralizing the null bytes, replacing them with spaces.  Firefox 15 on Windows 7 is rendering the null bytes.  You may be able to see them if you use a program such as [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to read the raw HTML as you load the page.

**Edit 2:** I'm not able to see any null bytes in Wireshark.  I got null bytes when I pasted it to HxD, but when I pasted it into Notepad++ with the correct encoding, saved the file, and opened it in HxD, I saw proper Unicode `e2 80 8b`.  It turns out HxD did not read the Unicode correctly, so this is [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro).

Comment: ‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮

Comment: Hmmmm I see the issue ^ [That was a bunch of RTL characters btw]

Comment: At last, it's your time to shine!

Comment: Wait, didn't we filter those out a long time ago due to people abusing them for fun and profit? I could have sworn we did, or was that just whitespace?

Comment: It's absolutely not clear if null bytes can be entered into posts and comments. Unicode zero-width space characters, byte order markers and RTL indicators have nothing to do with the null bytes discussed in those security advisories.

Comment: When I try to submit a post containing 0x00 bytes, I get the "body is missing" error. Can you elaborate on how this is used to circumvent the length limit?

Comment: (I get that error if there are any NULs, not just if the message is only NULs, but maybe setting NUL chars w/ JS is different.) I'd also like to know how you could tell that there were NUL bytes in Welbot's post, according to your hex editor. As far as I can tell (maybe I'm using the wrong commands), they don't appear to be in the source of the  on the edit page (`curl http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/10518/edit | hexdump -C | grep " 00 "`) or the question page (`curl http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/enforcing-a-question-minimum-character-length/ |  hexdump -C | grep " 00 "`).

Comment: I clicked on the 'edit' link, hit Control-A to select all of the (invisible) text, and pasted it into the [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) hex editor.  The editor showed `0x00`--null bytes.

Comment: @DragonLordtheFiery Ah... when I try the same thing (select-all, copy, then `pbpaste | hexdump`) I actually see `e2 80 8b` repeatedly - the non-breaking space character.

Comment: @TheElementofMagic - When I request that page and look at the response in Fiddler HexView I see the exact same thing as you.

Comment: It works if I copy null bytes from a source and paste it into the field.  This could be due to the way the browser is rendering it.  On Firefox 15, the null bytes are indeed being rendered.  Try using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to extract the HTML being sent over the network.

Comment: @DragonLordtheFiery - The bytes sent over the network are compressed. Fiddler just uncompresses it without changing anything AFAIK and shows `e2 80 8b`

Comment: @MartinSmith, what OS and browser are you running?  Also, have you refreshed the page bypassing the cache?

Comment: Doubt it makes any difference what OS and browser I'm using as fiddler acts as a proxy between the browser and the server. Have you actually bothered looking at the network traffic your end as you are advising others to do? If you confirm you have and you see something different I'll let you know.

Comment: I captured the network traffic for the edit page using WireShark and used its built-in HTTP filter to decompress the traffic. There are no  NUL bytes. I think this report is in error. [CC @MartinSmith]

Comment: I didn't see any null bytes.  I'm not sure what's going on, though...

Comment: How would this even be an issue? If having null bytes in HTML would cause issues in some browser, it's the browser that needs to be fixed ASAP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you may have *posted* your [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137006/dont-count-non-printing-characters-html-comments-or-other-content-not-displaye/137018#137018) with null bytes, and that may have let you circumvent the minimum character limit, the post is not, in fact, served with null bytes, and so there is no related security issue.

If you see any null bytes in this post, it's because your browser is mangling it. Report a bug against your browser.

You can download the HTML file and look at the source. You'll see:

```
    <div class="post-text"><p>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​</p>
</div>
```

This may not be very visible: there's a bunch of [U+200B ZERO WIDTH SPACE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) between the `<p>` and the `</p>`. An alternate way to write the same content would be.

```
    <div class="post-text"><p>&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;&x200B;</p>
</div>
```

You get the same content from the [API version 1](http://api.meta.stackoverflow.com/1.1/answers/137018?body=true) or [API version 2](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/answers/137018?order=desc&sort=activity&site=meta.stackoverflow&filter=!-u2CTCBE).

I checked Firefox 10 (Iceweasel from Debian squeeze) and Chrome stable (21.0.1180.81), and both do render zero-width spaces.