# You can make a mostly empty comment/post using link Markdown

Tags: bug, status-declined, comments

If  you type the following in a comment, you can post an (almost) empty comment:

```
[.](http://about:blank)
```

Here's an example of that:

> [.](http://about:blank)

I've also included an example of that code in the comments of this question.

In posts, since you can use HTML, you can use empty strikethrough to make a completely invisible link (which is useless):

```
[<s></s>](http://about:blank)
```

Here's an example of that:

> 

Comment: [.](http://about:blank)

Comment: Related: [Don't count non-printing characters, HTML comments or other content not displayed toward minimum character requirements](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137006/dont-count-non-printing-characters-html-comments-or-other-content-not-displaye)

Comment: [‌](http://google.com)

Comment: As can be seen above, you can have a completely blank comment.  Just use a non-breaking space in the brackets.  I did `[‌](http://google.com)`

Comment: **But... Why?**

Comment: @animuson Speaking of loopholes in post length restrictions, could you please destroy [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327336/6304349) for good?

Comment: ­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: [‌](http://google.com)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also create a new account and upvote yourself.

You can also [build castles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1974/152859) using `<kbd>` tags.

So what? Being able to do things doesn't mean you should be doing them, and surely this isn't a bug in the system.