# Remove the useless 15-character requirement for comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, character-limit

A comment saying something short like "I did." or "It is." in response to another comment is perfectly legitimate. What's the point in requiring users to fill it up with pointless "..." or other characters?

Comment: **How** much is it?

Comment: Zort‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏‏!

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/700/can-we-get-rid-of-the-threshold-of-15-chars-for-comments and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17183/do-away-with-minimum-char-limits-on-comments