# Why have a comment min char limit?

Tags: bug, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do away with minimum char limits on comments.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17183/do-away-with-minimum-char-limits-on-comments)

What's wrong with with simply saying 'thanks' or 'cool'? I instead have to type 'thanks..................... :)', 'cool................. :)' and so on. Why have this restriction? Is there something wrong with simply thanking someone?

Comment: I see what you did there

Comment: Good opportunity to remember the first "me too" on usenet: http://groups.google.com/group/net.micro.pc/msg/993d3e017d041ed4 (that is, according to http://www.google.com/googlegroups/archive_announce_20.html)

Comment: `​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​`

Comment: The limit s there **to** prevent that (well, to make you work at it, anyway).

Comment: @Click Upvote: Note that I will flag any comment that is just "thanks" or "cool". These comments are nothing but noise and take away space from real comments when they're folded up in the initial view.

Comment: and I will flag them also (because one flag doesn't really do anything)

Comment: @Arjan van Bentem: I wasn't even born..

Answer (score 12):

IMHO, comments should be used for more than saying **thanks**, they should enrich a post.

Short comments like **thanks** or **cool** are just noise

Comment: That's perhaps what you think but if someone takes the time to answer my question they would be happy to see a quick thanks message, plus its common courtesy.

Comment: I still don't agree. Upvote them to show them courtesy, and comment only to add value

Comment: @Click Upvote: Upvotes are for giving a quick thanks. Comments are for asking for clarification and holding short discussions. What you think they're for is irrelevant, because their use is well defined.

Comment: The people who take the time to answer a question are still a human behind the screen. A robot would be satisfied with just an upvote, humans appreciate if someone thanks them verbally.

Comment: Last time I checked, I was human, and I prefer an upvote thank you very much

Comment: @Click Upvote: The site runs on votes, not thanks.

Comment: Personally the words thank you has lost a lot of meaning when you read it 20 times a day. Hearing the words Cool makes me feel like I am on a school ground. Slang has place, but not on a professional developer Q&A.

Comment: @Downvoter I doubt you post many helpful answers longer than a few lines. I'm talking about when someone does a lot of research and gives you a detailed answer, they deserve more than an upvote.

Comment: @Click, add a bounty to your question, and award it to them

Comment: Dammit, @Urdnot, you got there before I did. And I had a better edit comment than you: "A noble spirit embiggens the smallest man" ...

Comment: @Downvoter it takes 48 hours before you can start a bounty and there's a high chance many people would forget it by then. And many people get good answers and don't have enough rep to start a bounty

Answer (score 6):

**Comments are for dialog, not for love notes.**

Comment: Can we have this in bold please.

Comment: @Diago: You're a moderator.

Comment: ♥​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​♡♥♡

Comment: @Urdnot - And? Doesn't mean I can just go and edit someone else's post. This is Meta. We are the bad guys here remember :)

Comment: @Diago: You're the bad guy because you obviously have no idea what being a moderator means. This phenomenon is not local to Meta, lest you forget your sillywhilstling last week on SU threatening users.

Comment: @Urdnot. You're welcome to enlighten me then. I obviously did sleep through my moderation lessons when I was in school. :)

Comment: ...So...who likes ponies...