# Why the 15 character minimum on comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

It gets annoying if the answer to another comment is short.

Edit: My answerable question: Is there a documentation about why?

Comment: Everyone knows the trick now...

Comment: Of course. We should probably use it less, or it will get fixed...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why have a comment min char limit?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39840/why-have-a-comment-min-char-limit)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Super short comments, in general, have little value.

From this [meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17183/do-away-with-minimum-char-limits-on-comments/23574#23574) by Jeff:

> ...perhaps one should consider populating their comment with something meaningful of 15 characters or more?

And, another [meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/700/can-we-get-rid-of-the-threshold-of-15-chars-for-comments) about this topic.

(That is the team's reasoning.  I'm not saying I agree.)

<sub>If you really wanna submit a short comment, you can bypass the filter by adding a blank link like so: `Hi [ ](http://example.com)` That will produce the comment 'Hi'.</sub>

Comment: What if I really want to say "Thanks!" or I want to answer what's my OS? .. Is there a documentation about why? That is my question. I will make an edit.

Comment: @cjava, I posted a link to an answer given by jeff that kinda answers your question.

Comment: "Thank you, that worked." and "I'm using Windows XP with SP3." are both long enough, no? "thnku" and "xpsp3" are less clear.

Comment: @cjava if you want to say thanks CAST AN UPVOTE. That is what they are for. Don't clutter up the world with a bunch of "thanks!" stuff.

Comment: Super-long comments can also have little value, as well as medium ones. Granted, a super-short one will often have "little value", but they can useful or funny.

Comment: There are times a short comment is relevant - answering "Yes" or "No" to a direct question, for instance. It'd be nice if shorter comments were enabled for users with a certain amount of rep, at least.

Comment: thanks[.](http://for.the.tip)

Comment: Hi [َ](http://example.com)