# Why we need to have 15 character comment on SO?

Tags: discussion, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why the 15 character minimum on comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68638/why-the-15-character-minimum-on-comments)

I dont understand use of having typing atleast 15 char for adding your comment. I mean, you can type thanks for your comment. And then you need to add more period (.) after your comment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are not supposed to post "Thanks." as a comment.

If an answer was helpful to you, accept it and / or vote it up.