# Can we get a whitelist of short comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments

Comments less than 15 characters are rejected, but in some cases (e.g. "link?") it often looks silly to tack on more writing just to pad it out. Up until now, I'd just add 10 spaces before the '?' but that doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/700/can-we-get-rid-of-the-threshold-of-15-chars-for-comments/23575#23575

Comment: What​​​​​​​​​​?

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​I thought 0-width spaces worked for this? (U+200B) ...

Comment: @Welbog: How?َََ

Comment: How?َََََََََََ

Comment: Ea‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏sy

Answer (score 2):

The 15 character comment minimum has actually been put in place just to prevent short comments as the ones you're referring to. They're nothing more than noise. If you can't say it in more than 15 chars, it probably shouldn't be said.

Comment: -1, for a very limited list of comments, the minimum forces you to ADD noise just to say something. For example the least noisy way I can think of to ask someone for a link to something they reference is "link?" but to get it to submit, you need to use something like "hyper Link ????" or "do you have a link to <the only thing in the post>?". Either of those is harder to parse than the short version.

Comment: +1 If "Got a link for that?" is _sooo_ much harder to type (and read) than "link?" you need to read or exercise more. Complete sentences are good.

Comment: How many answers have you seen that would be improved by adding some links? How many do you care enough about to type "Got a link for that?"? The cost's not that high but even so, the profit margin is so darn thin.

Comment: [citation needed]

Answer (score -1):

Why not just insert an HTML comment `<!-- like this -->`?

Comment: <!-- lololololololololol -->

Comment: ^--- that's why

Comment: Huh.  You can still do this in answers; they must have removed this ability for comments.

Comment: No, they didn't.

Comment: Hacking around the system is generally a bad thing. Adjusting the system is generally a better thing.

Comment: @BCS: The reason there's a minimum bound is to prevent noise. If everyone could just respond, easily, "+1" or ":)", there would be a zillion noisy comments. That some hacks may work is a feature -- it still requires enough effort to go through the hack to prevent most pure noise comments.

Comment: @Brad: he did say **most** not **all**...

Comment: That's why I'm asking for a white list. Because MOST but not ALL short comments are junk. "+1" might be junk from most people, but from the OP it say a lot. "Link?" often says all I have to say. If you have to pad it out, a lot of people will just add junk or not even bother.

Comment: How does +1 say anything different coming from the OP than it does coming from J. Random SOpedian? The OP might be asking about how to parse HTML with a regex, and +1 from him means you're working for Cthulhu.

Comment: from the OP +1 says this is useful and relevent to the question that is being asked (not always a easy thing to tell) even if it's not a complete answer. From anyone else, it just says "that's cool".