# Why in comment I have to put at least 15 chars?

Tags: discussion, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we get rid of the threshold of 15 chars for comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/700/can-we-get-rid-of-the-threshold-of-15-chars-for-comments)

Is there any logical reason for that? And just to prove how unnatural it is: Why can't I simply say thanks?

Why do I have to type unrelated text to post my comment? Ridiculous, unnatural, frustrating.

Comment: It has a long history on meta, by the way. There way several methods to "circumvent" it and people claimed it was a "bug" in the system and Jeff became angry one day and decided to shut off all the holes.

Comment: dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/700/can-we-get-rid-of-the-threshold-of-15-chars-for-comments

Comment: @eth, I only know one...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect it's precisely to discourage comments such as "Thanks" or "Me too". Thank someone by upvoting them - the text is just noise when you consider SO as a repository of meaningful information.