# Exception to 15 character comment limit for "Thanks"?

Tags: feature-request, comments, character-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we get rid of the threshold of 15 chars for comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/700/can-we-get-rid-of-the-threshold-of-15-chars-for-comments)

I think it would be rather peachy to allow a grace on the minimum 15 characters needed for a comment for such morsels as "Thanks".

I believe that this would perhaps encourage more niceness on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This place is too friendly as it is.

Comment: see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/700/can-we-get-rid-of-the-threshold-of-15-chars-for-comments

Answer (score 16):

An up-vote is a much better "thank you" than a "thanks" comment!

Comment: Both is even better..

Comment: @izb: *Not* in the spirit of Stack Overflow, where such comments are seen as "noise".

Comment: I disagree. a "Thanks" from one person in one post is courteous, not noise. As for the upvote, I agree, but I also think both is better.

Answer (score 16):

> Thanks

is noise. But

> Thanks; that even improved performance by 25%. Awesome!

or

> Thanks, I appreciate that you went through all those details.

are 1. nice and 2. longer than 15 characters.

Comment: -1 I do not agree with it... a simple "Many thanks :)" would put a smile in the user that answer it... and though, it's still a char left ... so I have to use "Many thanks :o)" instead :-/

Comment: @balexandre Seriously, when someone posts an unqualified "thanks" on my answer, that doesn't make me smile -- I feel they just do that because they think they have to. If they say "thanks, that's great because such and such", *then* it feels like a real "thank you". And *then*, they also need more then 15 chars

Comment: @balpha I'm guessing you hate "thx" just like me. They couldn't even be bothered typing out the full word.