# Preserving white space in comments

Tags: support, comments, markdown, whitespace

Since I don't think we can use the `<pre>` tag, is there a way to preserve white space in comments?  Backticks by themselves don't seem to do it:

Using backticks:
`testing     extra spaces`

Using `<code>` tag:
`testing     extra spaces`

Using `<pre>` tag:

```
testing     extra spaces
```

Using "Code Sample" toolbar button (Ctrl+K) (I guess this is the same as `<pre><code>`):

```
testing     extra spaces
```

Comment: Comments only have a few features because they are meant to be secondary to the answers, and not meant to contain important information.  Can you give an example of, or explain why, comments need this feature?  It may take quite a bit of convincing to get it accepted.

Comment: @Adam: [This is the comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327512/convert-html-to-plain-text-in-vba/5334547#5334547) that prompted me to ask this question.  It doesn't seem like enough to post a separate answer.  I retagged this question to "support", since I don't really expect anything to be changed.  I just wanted to know if there was a way.

Comment: @Cheran: You can't use `<code>` in comments anyway, can you? Let me try: <code>testing     extra spaces</code>. So no, not possible. What you can do _in questions and answers_: `<code>testing &nbsp; extra spaces</code>`. In comments there still might be a way with crazy unicode spaces.

Comment: Agree; in passages surrounded by  `, whitespace should be preserved.

Comment: You use to be able to do the ol' backtick hackery trick: two spaces: ` ` ` ` -- but I think that broke a while ago. &nbsp;

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: how did you do that?  When I type HTML entities, they just show up as plain text (i.e. &#160;)

Comment: try this   out....ah, okay, you're just typing in the actual non-breaking space character.  I think that's a workable solution!  Thanks!

Comment: @Cher doing it by holding `ALT` and pressing 255 in the keypad - the ♪♫ are there as well. ☻

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per @Shadow Wizard's comment, you can type a non-breaking space character by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+255 on the keypad (or alternatively, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+0160).  For example

```
`two  spaces`
```

is rendered as

```
<code>two&#160;&#160;spaces</code>
```

and the spaces are preserved.

EDIT: As Arjan pointed out, this should not be used when posting code, since someone could copy and paste it into their editor, and it possibly won't compile.

Comment: ...even if this [is never removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79698/can-we-have-backticks-in-comments-back-please), then the fragments are no longer true code. Copy & paste might then fail with odd compile messages?

Comment: @Arjan correct as usual, this should not be used to post code.. though never tried to compile code with those characters - anyone care to pick the glove? ;)

Comment: Good point, @Arjan.  I hadn't thought about people copying and pasting.

Answer (score 2):

There's something odd about this.

When I leave the comment

```
this is a `code span with single space` a `code  span  with  double  space`
```

The rendered HTML is

```
<span class="comment-copy">
    this is a 
    <code>code span with single space</code> 
    a 
    <code>code  span  with  double  space</code>
</span>
```

So the whitespace is indeed correctly preserved **in the source HTML**

Comment: this is a `code span with single space` a `code  span  with  double  space`

Comment: I'm encouraged by reading that _you_ find that odd, Jeff `:-)`

Comment: @hendrik meh, I don't think `<code>` does anything except switch the font as balpha pointed out to me.

Comment: Indeed, @Jeff: `<code>` should not render excessive whitespace. (That would then also include newlines et al. `<code>` is simply not `<pre>`.)

Comment: Thanks, that's really good to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Comment: Nice, but that would also enable newlines. That [has been declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197/how-about-newlines-within-comments) for comments.