# multiple spaces in backticks (``) are not converted into unbreakable ones

Tags: support, markdown, backtick

When I try to use

```
`hi       another text`
```

it returns me `hi       another text` - spaces are breaked.

Comment: Use the `{ }` button in the markdown editor. It preserves multiple spaces.

Comment: @RobertHarvey He knows that, he used that feature to ask the question.

Comment: @agf: Meh.  Multiple spaces in a single line of code is exceedingly rare (except maybe in the Whitespace language).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83522/preserving-white-space-in-comments

Comment: It's a CSS issue. When you use `<code>` tags (which are generated by the backticks), multiple spaces are collapsed into one by your browser.

Answer (score 6):

The fact that non-breaking spaces render in html as separate characters rather than a single character is a **side-effect** of what `&nbsp;` is really about: line breaks.  The non-breaking space is considered *significant* white space (as opposed to normal insignificant whitespace) for the purpose of preventing text from wrapping to a new line at that location. It has **nothing** to do with showing wider gaps/multiple spaces between words, and the fact that it often does so is a mere accident or side effect of the significant whitespace designation.

Once you realize this, rendering spaces from inline code blocks using `&nbsp;` makes absolutely no sense.  It might be a good idea to do something else to make this white-space significant rather than insignificant, but a non-breaking space is not the way to go.

A better option would be to use U+2002 (en space) or U+2003 (em space): `&ensp;` or `&emsp;` (or `&#x2002;` / `&#x2003;`).

Answer (score 4):

Like most things that aren't needed often enough to be in the Markdown syntax, you can achieve this using HTML.

```
<code>hi&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;another text</code>.
```

The result is `hi     another text`.

You can also use the unicode non-breaking space character `U+00A0` inside backticks. You can copy them from the character map (or from this post).

```
`hi     another text`
   ^^^^^
   non-breaking spaces
```

The result is `hi     another text`.

Answer (score 4):

You don't actually want non-*breaking* spaces; the results aren't pretty (this styling is meant to allow inline code, which depending on its position in the text may well need to be broken across multiple lines - spaces are a pretty good place to do this). You simply want the spaces to be preserved in the output, which the Markdown renderer *does*, but your browser does not. Adding the style,

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

...to the `code` tag would correct this. As [hammar notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107083/multiple-spaces-in-backticks-are-not-converted-into-unbreakable-ones/107087#107087), you can work around the current lack of such styling by manually inserting `&nbsp;` into a `<code>` span... However, to avoid ugly breaking, I suggest altering spaces and non-breaking spaces:

```
<code>hi&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;another text</code>
```

You can see the difference here: after some text to push the code toward the end of the line `hi     another text`. Vs. some other text to put the code with alternate non-breaking spaces `hi     another text` (note the wasted space at the end of the first line as the entire line of code was wrapped).

Comment: As an aside: the `pre-wrap` is used on the mobile sites, to allow for [wrapping the `<pre>` blocks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98776/stack-exchange-mobile-launched/103249#103249). Anyone who doesn't know it: click the mobile link in the footer to see how that wrapping works, while still preserving the whitespace.

Comment: As an alternative to putting spaces between the non-breaking spaces, you could put zero-width spaces (`&#x200B`) in instead. Then, you'll always see the exact number of spaces that you want, even when the line breaks in the middle of them.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to type <kbd>Alt</kbd> + (<kbd>Keypad 0</kbd> <kbd>Keypad 1</kbd> <kbd>Keypad 6</kbd> <kbd>Keypad 0</kbd>) which also allows you to write `hi     another text`.

Comment: Windows only, of course, but a convenient solution.