# My comment `code block` was not converted properly, is this a bug?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, code-formatting, markdown

In my comment here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409/what-is-your-favorite-coding-guidelines-checklist/138993#comment-8835926

I needed to have a `:` symbol with a leading space, but I couldn't figure out how to get it.  And for some reason it converts differently in this question to how it would in a comment - as you can see, in the comment box `` ` :` `` wasn't turned into code block at all.  Is it impossible, by design, to have leading or trailing space in a `codeblock`?

Comment: testing ` :` 123 ``` :```

Comment: Very interesting.

Comment: Comments use a different Markdown "mini" parser, which explains how there's a difference, but I can't imagine this is by design. It actually causes an obscure bug in chat as well, since the client-side Markdown mini parser converts it as expected, only to have the server-side parser switch it back to its raw-text form.

Comment: Oh, interesting. `:` and ` :`... Seems that only the leading space case doesn't work - the former works as expected.

Comment: testing ` untrimmed` `trimmed`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  Closed as not constructive.  Snake!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Citing [Jeff's first comment to this answer about inline code in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79254/recent-change-of-inline-code-in-comments-leads-to-mistakes-in-old-comments/79344#79344):

> Spaces are not allowed as the start or end character in inline code blocks now. Do not include them, or it won't work.

That said, as a workaround you can put a zero-width unicode character '‍' (yeah, it's right there between the apostrophes) at the start of your inline code; then you can put a space after that character. Note, however, that what looks like a zero-width character to you [may appear to be some odd character to them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79698/can-we-have-backticks-in-comments-back-please/79699#79699). Moreover, if people copy-and-paste that code from your comment, they may catch the zero-width character without noticing.

So in your case, putting `` `‍ :` `` in the comment should work (tested below).

Comment: To demonstrate that it works: `‍ :`

Comment: And then people copy-past zero-width characters in their code and wonder why it doesn't work...