# Comments - Code block markup doesn't display correctly

Tags: bug, status-norepro, android-app

Using grave accent ` doesn't format the code in the comments.

A screenshot is worth many words:

[image]

Comment: Your font is peculiar...although it doesn't affect the fixed width font you've got up above.

Comment: The answer was posted via the web UI version earlier, I have not tried answering using the app with code formatting using both methods (indentation or grave accent) yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222820/dropdown-list-for-different-model-in-yii#comment26714696_18223197) originally had a space after the first backtick. That [never renders as code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105316/my-comment-code-block-was-not-converted-properly-is-this-a-bug), neither on the web nor in the app. You then edited your comment to remove that leading (and trailing) space, and now it shows up correctly. Granted, code and normal text aren't actually distinguishable in comments in the app, but the backticks are not visible when I look at the question in the app. Your screenshot is from before your edit.