# Compromise for the minimum character limit for comments

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, character-limit

My original suggestion was: Change the minimum character limit for comments to an “Are you sure” instead of a requirement - similar to the minimum for question titles.

I think that Sid Meier had a good idea: *"new users can't post short comments, intermediate users can post short comments but are asked if they're sure, and advanced users can post short comments without any prompts"*

I think that we should make sure we tell the new users why they can't post short comments (so they learn) and also tell them that higher reputation will remove the restrictions.

Also please do not make any more comments on this question that just prove the system can be tricked.

**Edit:** Looks like we better make sure we don't let the high rep users forget the reason that they were blocked from short comments to begin with

Edit: ***Oh Well***, it looks like this idea is not going very well. Perhaps you should still upvote my question if you want the limit changed... and this question: [Can we get rid of the threshold of 15 chars for comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/700/can-we-get-rid-of-the-threshold-of-15-chars-for-comments)

Comment: Just what kind of comments under 15 characters do you want to post?

Comment: I am not trying to answer that question. I just wanted to put up a compromise suggestion about the are you sure and see how it gets voted. There are two ups and two downs so far.

Comment: You know what? I've changed my mind. I'm with you on this suggestion. Hard limits are stupid. So let's go with a slightly different but similar suggestion: new users can't post short comments, intermediate users can post short comments but are asked if they're sure, and advanced users can post short comments without any prompts. That way we keep the noise comments (e.g. "thx") out with a hard limit until users have been around long enough to know that such comments are unwelcome. Then you only have the soft limit for when a short comment really is necessary.

Comment: Are you really sure?

Comment: I'm declining the compromise idea ... the restriction removal is already covered here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/700/can-we-get-rid-of-the-threshold-of-15-chars-for-comments .. I am not against improving the warnings

Comment: Personally I loathe the **15 seconds; timer reset. 15 seconds; timer reset** thing far more than the 15 character limit.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Can you please point me to the relevant burninate discussion thread for the [tag:thresholds] tag? Please note that [there is consensus against removing tags here without a burninate discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320516/why-are-tags-on-mse-being-regularly-removed-deprecated-without-discussion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not buying the whole users with 1000 rep should be allowed to post short comments argument. I do not consider it a privilege to post short comments. A lot of the short comment abuse was coming from high rep users anyway.

If you want to type `Yes` `No` and `OK`, well we have [chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com) for that.

I am not against improving our UI so it clarifies stuff better, perhaps a ? linked to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment when you try to submit a short comment or something like it.

Comment: Waffles, how do you suggest someone respond when asked a yes-or-no question in a comment? There are legitimate non-spam reasons to post short comments. A comment's value is not a function of its length. The 15-character limit is arbitrary and meaningless. It accomplishes a goal: removing short, noisy comments. It does not remove long, noisy comments and is disallows short, meaningful comments. High-rep users are unlikely to post "thanks" or "lol" because they know the culture of SO. New users still need the limiter in place to help them learn it, but the restriction is arbitrary and wrong.

Comment: Yea, what *do* you suggest? And I don't expect to post my question's on chat just because I might get a Yes/No question. We can't stop the abuse by a character limit. There are other buttons or warnings that at least give the decision to a human.

Comment: @Sid , @cjavapro This question appears to be about a compromise ... not http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/700/can-we-get-rid-of-the-threshold-of-15-chars-for-comments ... I am strongly against a compromise that unlocks the ability for short comments for high rep users. It does not make sense to me.

Comment: It's scientific fact that comment quality is unrelated to length. Therefore it's scientific fact that restricting comment length in an effort to improve quality doesn't make any sense. Therefore it's scientific fact that you're wrong.

Comment: @Sid ... that is a separate issue all together ...  and its the other feature Jeff declined ages ago.

Comment: Jeff was wrong then and he's still wrong. Siding with someone whom science can prove is wrong is wrong.

Comment: So, you guys trust me to close and delete questions, edit any post on the site and even move questions to other sites, but I cannot add the occasional "what?" comment?

Comment: @Kobi ... this whole post has been derailed by @Sid and co. It is dealing with the concept of giving special "short comment privs" to users, because people are upset about http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/700/can-we-get-rid-of-the-threshold-of-15-chars-for-comments being declined. I am strongly against having "short comments" as a priv, its either everyone can have ultra short comments or no one.

Comment: And the short comment discussion is covered there ... personally ... I don't see what the big fuss is ... its a restriction ... at times it can be annoying but overall it does not cause too much pain

Comment: Just replace the "15 more to go" with. Please avoid meaningless comments like lol, etc.. and then when they hit 15 you can make it go away..